# Is it possible to draw a boxplot given the percentile values instead of the original inputs?

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, percentile

From what I can see, `boxplot()` method expects a sequence of raw values (numbers) as input, from which it then computes percentiles to draw the boxplot(s).

I would like to have a method by which I could pass in the percentiles and get the corresponding `boxplot`.

For example:

Assume that I have run several benchmarks and for each benchmark I've measured latencies ( floating point values ). Now additionally, I have precomputed the percentiles for these values.

Hence for each benchmark, I have the 25th, 50th, 75th percentile along with the min and max.

Now given these data, I would like to draw the box plots for the benchmarks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To draw the box plot using just the percentile values and the outliers ( if any ) I made a `customized_box_plot` function that basically modifies attributes in a basic box plot ( generated from a tiny sample data ) to make it fit according to your percentile values.

**The `customized_box_plot` function**

```
def customized_box_plot(percentiles, axes, redraw = True, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Generates a customized boxplot based on the given percentile values
    """
    
    box_plot = axes.boxplot([[-9, -4, 2, 4, 9],]*n_box, *args, **kwargs) 
    # Creates len(percentiles) no of box plots
    
    min_y, max_y = float('inf'), -float('inf')
    
    for box_no, (q1_start, 
                 q2_start,
                 q3_start,
                 q4_start,
                 q4_end,
                 fliers_xy) in enumerate(percentiles):
        
        # Lower cap
        box_plot['caps'][2*box_no].set_ydata([q1_start, q1_start])
        # xdata is determined by the width of the box plot

        # Lower whiskers
        box_plot['whiskers'][2*box_no].set_ydata([q1_start, q2_start])

        # Higher cap
        box_plot['caps'][2*box_no + 1].set_ydata([q4_end, q4_end])

        # Higher whiskers
        box_plot['whiskers'][2*box_no + 1].set_ydata([q4_start, q4_end])

        # Box
        box_plot['boxes'][box_no].set_ydata([q2_start, 
                                             q2_start, 
                                             q4_start,
                                             q4_start,
                                             q2_start])
        
        # Median
        box_plot['medians'][box_no].set_ydata([q3_start, q3_start])

        # Outliers
        if fliers_xy is not None and len(fliers_xy[0]) != 0:
            # If outliers exist
            box_plot['fliers'][box_no].set(xdata = fliers_xy[0],
                                           ydata = fliers_xy[1])
            
            min_y = min(q1_start, min_y, fliers_xy[1].min())
            max_y = max(q4_end, max_y, fliers_xy[1].max())
            
        else:
            min_y = min(q1_start, min_y)
            max_y = max(q4_end, max_y)
                    
        # The y axis is rescaled to fit the new box plot completely with 10% 
        # of the maximum value at both ends
        axes.set_ylim([min_y*1.1, max_y*1.1])

    # If redraw is set to true, the canvas is updated.
    if redraw:
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        
    return box_plot
```

**USAGE**

Using inverse logic ( code at the very end ) I extracted the percentile values from this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo2.html#pylab-examples-example-code-boxplot-demo2-py)

```
>>> percentiles
(-1.0597368367634488, 0.3977683984966961, 1.0298955252405229, 1.6693981537742526, 3.4951447843464449)
(-0.90494930553559483, 0.36916539612108634, 1.0303658700697103, 1.6874542731392828, 3.4951447843464449)
(0.13744105279440233, 1.3300645202649739, 2.6131540656339483, 4.8763411136047647, 9.5751914834437937)
(0.22786243898199182, 1.4120860286080519, 2.637650402506837, 4.9067126578493259, 9.4660357513550899)
(0.0064696168078617741, 0.30586770128093388, 0.70774153557312702, 1.5241965711101928, 3.3092932063051976)
(0.007009744579241136, 0.28627373934008982, 0.66039691869500572, 1.4772725266672091, 3.221716765477217)
(-2.2621660374110544, 5.1901313713883352, 7.7178532139979357, 11.277744848353247, 20.155971739152388)
(-2.2621660374110544, 5.1884411864079532, 7.3357079047721054, 10.792299385806913, 18.842012119715388)
(2.5417888074435702, 5.885996170695587, 7.7271286220368598, 8.9207423361593179, 10.846938621419374)
(2.5971767318505856, 5.753551925927133, 7.6569980004033464, 8.8161056254143233, 10.846938621419374)
```

Note that to keep this short I haven't shown the outliers vectors which will be the 6th element of each of the percentile array.

Also note that all usual additional kwargs / args can be used since they are simply passed to the `boxplot` method inside it :

```
>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>>> b = customized_box_plot(percentiles, ax, redraw=True, notch=0, sym='+', vert=1, whis=1.5)
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: Box Plot using Percentile values]

**EXPLANATION**

The `boxplot` method returns a dictionary mapping the components of the boxplot to the individual `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` instances that were created.

Quoting from the `matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot` documentation :

> That dictionary has the following keys (assuming vertical boxplots):
>
> boxes: the main body of the boxplot showing the quartiles and the median’s confidence intervals if enabled.
>
> medians: horizonal lines at the median of each box.
>
> whiskers: the vertical lines extending to the most extreme, n-outlier data points. caps: the horizontal lines at the ends of the whiskers.
>
> fliers: points representing data that extend beyond the whiskers (outliers).
>
> means: points or lines representing the means.

For example observe the `boxplot` of a tiny sample data of `[-9, -4, 2, 4, 9]`

```
>>> b = ax.boxplot([[-9, -4, 2, 4, 9],])
>>> b
{'boxes': [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fe1f5b21350>],
'caps': [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fe1f54d4e50>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fe1f54d0e50>],
'fliers': [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fe1f5b317d0>],
'means': [],
'medians': [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fe1f63549d0>],
'whiskers': [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fe1f5b22e10>,
             <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fe20c54a510>]} 

>>> plt.show()
```

[image: A Sample box plot]

The [`matplotlib.lines.Line2D`](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) objects have two methods that I'll be using in my function extensively. [`set_xdata`](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_xdata) ( or [`set_ydata`](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_ydata) ) and [`get_xdata`](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.get_xdata) ( or [`get_ydata`](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.get_ydata) ).

Using these methods we can alter the position of the constituent lines of the base box plot to conform to your percentile values ( which is what the `customized_box_plot` function does ). After altering the constituent lines' position, you can redraw the canvas using  `figure.canvas.draw()`

**Summarizing the mappings from percentile to the coordinates of the various `Line2D` objects.**

The Y Coordinates :

- The max ( `q4_end` - end of 4th quartile ) corresponds to the top most cap `Line2D` object.
- The min ( `q1_start` - start of the 1st quartile ) corresponds to the lowermost most cap `Line2D` object.
- The median corresponds to the ( `q3_start` ) median `Line2D` object.
- The 2 whiskers lie between the ends of the boxes and extreme caps ( `q1_start` and `q2_start` - lower whisker; `q4_start` and `q4_end` - upper whisker )
- The box is actually an interesting `n` shaped line bounded by a cap at the lower portion. The extremes of the `n` shaped line correspond to the `q2_start` and the `q4_start`.

The X Coordinates :

- The Central x coordinates ( for multiple box plots are usually 1, 2, 3... )
- The library automatically calculates the bounding x coordinates based on the width specified.

INVERSE FUNCTION TO RETRIEVE THE PERCENTILES FROM THE boxplot DICT:

```
def get_percentiles_from_box_plots(bp):
    percentiles = []
    for i in range(len(bp['boxes'])):
        percentiles.append((bp['caps'][2*i].get_ydata()[0],
                           bp['boxes'][i].get_ydata()[0],
                           bp['medians'][i].get_ydata()[0],
                           bp['boxes'][i].get_ydata()[2],
                           bp['caps'][2*i + 1].get_ydata()[0],
                           (bp['fliers'][i].get_xdata(),
                            bp['fliers'][i].get_ydata())))
    return percentiles
```

NOTE:
The reason why I did not make a completely custom boxplot method is because, there are many features offered by the inbuilt box plot that cannot be fully reproduced.

Also excuse me if I may have unnecessarily explained something that may have been too obvious.

Comment: three small problems encountered with this:
(1) n_box is not defined (this is easy...)
(2) if you wish to pass percentile data without fliers, the loop fails (better write for box_no, pdata in enumerate(percentiles) and then check len of pdata
(3) routine fails if you use patch_artist=True (no set_ydata method)

Answer (score 53):

As of 2020, there is a better method than the one in the accepted answer.

The `matplotlib.axes.Axes` class provides a [`bxp`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-bxp) method, which can be used to draw the boxes and whiskers based on the percentile values. Raw data is only needed for the outliers, and that is optional.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
boxes = [
    {
        'label' : "Male height",
        'whislo': 162.6,    # Bottom whisker position
        'q1'    : 170.2,    # First quartile (25th percentile)
        'med'   : 175.7,    # Median         (50th percentile)
        'q3'    : 180.4,    # Third quartile (75th percentile)
        'whishi': 187.8,    # Top whisker position
        'fliers': []        # Outliers
    }
]
ax.bxp(boxes, showfliers=False)
ax.set_ylabel("cm")
plt.savefig("boxplot.png")
plt.close()
```

This produces the following image: [image: example boxplot]

Comment: Best solution of all above! You can give multiple dictionaries within the boxes list and works perfectly for multiple box plots.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an updated version of this useful routine. Setting the vertices directly appears to work for both filled boxes (patchArtist=True) and unfilled ones.

```
def customized_box_plot(percentiles, axes, redraw = True, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Generates a customized boxplot based on the given percentile values
    """
    n_box = len(percentiles)
    box_plot = axes.boxplot([[-9, -4, 2, 4, 9],]*n_box, *args, **kwargs) 
    # Creates len(percentiles) no of box plots

    min_y, max_y = float('inf'), -float('inf')

    for box_no, pdata in enumerate(percentiles):
        if len(pdata) == 6:
            (q1_start, q2_start, q3_start, q4_start, q4_end, fliers_xy) = pdata
        elif len(pdata) == 5:
            (q1_start, q2_start, q3_start, q4_start, q4_end) = pdata
            fliers_xy = None
        else:
            raise ValueError("Percentile arrays for customized_box_plot must have either 5 or 6 values")

        # Lower cap
        box_plot['caps'][2*box_no].set_ydata([q1_start, q1_start])
        # xdata is determined by the width of the box plot

        # Lower whiskers
        box_plot['whiskers'][2*box_no].set_ydata([q1_start, q2_start])

        # Higher cap
        box_plot['caps'][2*box_no + 1].set_ydata([q4_end, q4_end])

        # Higher whiskers
        box_plot['whiskers'][2*box_no + 1].set_ydata([q4_start, q4_end])

        # Box
        path = box_plot['boxes'][box_no].get_path()
        path.vertices[0][1] = q2_start
        path.vertices[1][1] = q2_start
        path.vertices[2][1] = q4_start
        path.vertices[3][1] = q4_start
        path.vertices[4][1] = q2_start

        # Median
        box_plot['medians'][box_no].set_ydata([q3_start, q3_start])

        # Outliers
        if fliers_xy is not None and len(fliers_xy[0]) != 0:
            # If outliers exist
            box_plot['fliers'][box_no].set(xdata = fliers_xy[0],
                                           ydata = fliers_xy[1])

            min_y = min(q1_start, min_y, fliers_xy[1].min())
            max_y = max(q4_end, max_y, fliers_xy[1].max())

        else:
            min_y = min(q1_start, min_y)
            max_y = max(q4_end, max_y)

        # The y axis is rescaled to fit the new box plot completely with 10% 
        # of the maximum value at both ends
        axes.set_ylim([min_y*1.1, max_y*1.1])

    # If redraw is set to true, the canvas is updated.
    if redraw:
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()

    return box_plot
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bottom-up approach where the box_plot is build up using matplotlib's `vline`, `Rectangle`, and normal `plot` functions

```
def boxplot(df, ax=None, box_width=0.2, whisker_size=20, mean_size=10, median_size = 10 , line_width=1.5, xoffset=0,
                     color=0):
    """Plots a boxplot from existing percentiles.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df: pandas DataFrame
    ax: pandas AxesSubplot
        if to plot on en existing axes
    box_width: float
    whisker_size: float
        size of the bar at the end of each whisker
    mean_size: float
        size of the mean symbol
    color: int or rgb(list)
        If int particular color of property cycler is taken. Example of rgb: [1,0,0] (red)

    Returns
    -------
    f, a, boxes, vlines, whisker_tips, mean, median
    """

    if type(color) == int:
        color = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color'][color]

    if ax:
        a = ax
        f = a.get_figure()
    else:
        f, a = plt.subplots()

    boxes = []
    vlines = []
    xn = []
    for row in df.iterrows():
        x = row[0] + xoffset
        xn.append(x)

        # box
        y = row[1][25]
        height = row[1][75] - row[1][25]
        box = plt.Rectangle((x - box_width / 2, y), box_width, height)
        a.add_patch(box)
        boxes.append(box)

        # whiskers
        y = (row[1][95] + row[1][5]) / 2
        vl = a.vlines(x, row[1][5], row[1][95])
        vlines.append(vl)

    for b in boxes:
        b.set_linewidth(line_width)
        b.set_facecolor([1, 1, 1, 1])
        b.set_edgecolor(color)
        b.set_zorder(2)

    for vl in vlines:
        vl.set_color(color)
        vl.set_linewidth(line_width)
        vl.set_zorder(1)

    whisker_tips = []
    if whisker_size:
        g, = a.plot(xn, df[5], ls='')
        whisker_tips.append(g)

        g, = a.plot(xn, df[95], ls='')
        whisker_tips.append(g)

    for wt in whisker_tips:
        wt.set_markeredgewidth(line_width)
        wt.set_color(color)
        wt.set_markersize(whisker_size)
        wt.set_marker('_')

    mean = None
    if mean_size:
        g, = a.plot(xn, df['mean'], ls='')
        g.set_marker('o')
        g.set_markersize(mean_size)
        g.set_zorder(20)
        g.set_markerfacecolor('None')
        g.set_markeredgewidth(line_width)
        g.set_markeredgecolor(color)
        mean = g

    median = None
    if median_size:
        g, = a.plot(xn, df['median'], ls='')
        g.set_marker('_')
        g.set_markersize(median_size)
        g.set_zorder(20)
        g.set_markeredgewidth(line_width)
        g.set_markeredgecolor(color)
        median = g

    a.set_ylim(np.nanmin(df), np.nanmax(df))
    return f, a, boxes, vlines, whisker_tips, mean, median
```

This is how it looks in action:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

nopts = 12
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['mean'] = np.random.random(nopts) + 7
df['median'] = np.random.random(nopts) + 7
df[5] = np.random.random(nopts) + 4
df[25] = np.random.random(nopts) + 6
df[75] = np.random.random(nopts) + 8
df[95] = np.random.random(nopts) + 10
out = boxplot(df)
```

[image]