# Manually Drawing Box Plot Using Matplotlib with Outliers

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

By referring to this [Is it possible to draw a matplotlib boxplot given the percentile values instead of the original inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214537/is-it-possible-to-draw-a-matplotlib-boxplot-given-the-percentile-values-instead), I would like to draw a single box-plot given the five-number-summary and the outliers.

The answer given from the question is for multiple box-plots, and I have modified the code to suit for a single box-plot.

This is the code that I tried:

```py
def custom_boxplot(mini, q1, q2, q3, maxm, *outliers):
    """
    Input: 
        Five-number summary separated into different arguments;
        The following arguments after the summary are the outliers.
    Output:
        A boxplot drawn in the console.
    """
    figure = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
    ax = plt.gca()
    bp = plt.boxplot([mini, q1, q2, q3, maxm])
    fliers = bp['fliers']
    for v in outliers:
        fliers[0].set(xdata = 1, ydata = v)
    _all = [mini, q1, q2, q3, maxm] + list(outliers)
    _min, _max = min(_all), max(_all)
    ax.set_ylim([_min*0.9, _max*1.1])

    figure.canvas.draw()
```

However, when I tried to run with the following line

```py
custom_boxplot(43.2, 43.5, 51.05, 56.8, 69.3, 13.8, 21.2)
```

It outputted the box-plot with only one outlier from the last argument. I expected two data points of outlier are drawn in the box-plot for `13.8` and `21.2`.

I believe the error is somewhere around here:

```py
...
    for v in outliers:
        fliers[0].set(xdata = 1, ydata = v)
...
```

I understand that because I only have one boxplot, I can do the subscripting like `fliers[0]` to get the first box from the boxplot. `xdata = 1` because again I am setting this for the first box, and then `ydata=v` for setting the y-value of the outlier.
Where is the mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
def custom_boxplot(mini, q1, q2, q3, maxm, *outliers):
    """
    Input: 
        Five-number summary separated into different arguments;
        The following arguments after the summary are the outliers.
    Output:
        A boxplot drawn in the console.
    """
    figure = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
    ax = plt.gca()
    bp = plt.boxplot([mini, q1, q2, q3, maxm])
    fliers = bp['fliers']
    fliers[0].set(xdata = [1]*len(outliers), ydata = outliers)
    _all = [mini, q1, q2, q3, maxm] + list(outliers)
    _min, _max = min(_all), max(_all)
    ax.set_ylim([_min*0.9, _max*1.1])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: so `xdata` and `ydata` can accept array for multiple outliers. I have tried `ydata = outliers`, and it worked too. Any specific reasons why `ydata = [*outliers]`?