# How to Create a Boxplot / Group Boxplot from [Min ,Q1 ,Q2 ,Q3 ,Max] in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, statistics, boxplot

I want to create Boxplots , but I don't have the data itself and I have Min, Max, Q1, Q2 , Q3 instead . How can I do that in Python ?

Comment: ```sns.boxplot(x=[min_, q1, q2, q3, max_])```

Comment: See solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60415825/2375421 Possibly dupe question.